# Why doesn't aws function have access to elastic file system?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs, pulumi

I want to connect the AWS efs filesystem to a lambda function. The connection is done with accesspoint and a mount target. The Pulumi code that should do this is as follow:

```
export const lamdaExecutionRole = new aws.iam.Role("lamda-execution-role", {assumeRolePolicy: `{
 
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}`,



name:'lamda-execution-role',
 managedPolicyArns: [ 
     lamdaPolicy.arn,
     fileSystemPolicy.arn,
     vpcPolicy.arn,
     
     
 ]
}

);


export const lambdaFileSystem = new aws.efs.FileSystem("lamda-file-sysytem", {tags: {
    Name: "efs_for_lambda",
}})

const vpc = new  awsx.ec2.Vpc("vpc");
 const subnetIds = vpc.publicSubnetIds;

const lamdaSecurityGroup = new aws.ec2.SecurityGroup("lamda-security-group", {
  vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
})


export const montTarget = new aws.efs.MountTarget("mount-target", {
        fileSystemId: lambdaFileSystem.id,
        subnetId: subnetIds[0],
        
     })

export  const lamdaAccessPoint = new aws.efs.AccessPoint("lamda-access-point-scor", {
    fileSystemId: lambdaFileSystem.id,
    rootDirectory: {
        path: "/",
        creationInfo: {
            ownerGid: 1000,
            ownerUid: 1000,
            permissions: "777",
        },
    },
    posixUser: {
        gid: 1000,
        uid: 1000,
    },
})


export const lamda = new aws.lambda.Function("aws-lamda-function", {
    code: new pulumi.asset.FileArchive("../app/build/libs/HelloWorldServerless-all.jar"),   
    runtime: aws.lambda.Runtime.Java11,
    handler: "HelloWorldServerless.HelloWorld::handler",
    role: lamdaExecutionRole.arn,
    name: "hello-world",
    memorySize: 300,
    timeout: 100,
    fileSystemConfig: {arn: lamdaAccessPoint.arn, localMountPath :"/mnt/efs"},
    vpcConfig: {
        subnetIds: [subnetIds[0]],
        securityGroupIds: [lamdaSecurityGroup.id],
    },
    
    layers: [ 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:464622532012:layer:dd-trace-java:8',
              "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Extension:38"],    
    environment: {
        variables: {
            DD_API_KEY:"*******",
            DD_CAPTURE_LAMBDA_PAYLOAD: "false",
            DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER: "HelloWorldServerless.HelloWorld::handler",
            DD_LOG_LEVEL: "info",
            FUNCTION_NAME: "hello-world",
            DD_SERVICE: 'hello-world',
            DD_SITE: "datadoghq.eu",
            DD_VERSION: "0.1",
            DD_LOGS_INJECTION: 'true',
            DD_JMXFETCH_ENABLED: 'false',
            DD_TRACE_ENABLED: 'true',
            DD_ENV: 'dev',
            DD_MERGE_XRAY_TRACES: "false",
            DD_FLUSH_TO_LOG: "true"
        },
    },
},
{ dependsOn:montTarget} 
   )
```

When I run the test

```
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"; // ES Modules import

it("should be Hello World ", async  () => { 
    
   const client = new LambdaClient({region:"eu-north-1"});
   const inputPayload = {"body": "{ \"message\": \"Hello from Lambda!\" }"}
   const command = new InvokeCommand({FunctionName:"hello-world" ,Payload:JSON.stringify(inputPayload)});
   const response = await client.send(command);
   expect(response.StatusCode).toBe(200)
   const payLoad = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, response.Payload)
   expect(payLoad).toBe("{\"isBase64Encoded\":false,\"statusCode\":200,\"body\":\"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"HELLO FROM LAMBDA!\\\"}\"}")
   
})
```

I get following error message:
EFSMountConnectivityException: The function couldn't connect to the Amazon EFS file system with access point arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-north-1:888219289265:access-point/fsap-05aead28f4e33f496. Check your network configuration and try again.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions can indeed connect to EFS, but you must:

- Release the Lambda in the same VPC of the EFS target (see: [Configure a Lambda Function to access resources in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html))
- Make sure that the security groups associated with the Lambda has Outbound opened for the EFS port (2049) to the target EFS mount target IP (or, better, to the Security Group of the EFS target)
- The EFS File System security group must allow NFS (port 2049) inbound traffic from the Lambda security group or IP address range. (https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-invoke-efs)

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-invoke-efs according to this, we also need to allow inbound of NFS (2049)